# Converting Javascript array objects to uppercase

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var contacts =[];

function getInfo() {
    var firstName = prompt("Enter first name");
    var lastName = prompt("Enter last name");
    var emailId = prompt("Enter Email ID");
    var phoneNo = prompt("Enter Phone number");
    var fname, lname, email, phone;
    var person ={
        fname : firstName,
        lname : lastName,
        email : emailId,
        phone : phoneNo
    }
    contacts.push(person);  
}
```

How do I convert `contacts` array to uppercase? After converting the array to uppercase, I want to display the full name in alphabetical order as shown in the picture. Or is there any other way to accomplish without converting to uppercase?

[image]

Comment: your array contains objects, not strings. If you want to know how to convert the first and last name strings to uppercase, it is important that you ask that, not about converting "objects to uppercase", because that's impossible. Please update your question accordingly. Also note those `var fname, ...` do nothing. You declare them, and then never use them. The object property names "fname" etc you use for your `person` object have nothing to do with the variables `fname` etc.

Comment: You don't declare variables before you use them as properties in the creation of an object literal. In fact, the only thing that's doing is creating local `undefined` variables of those name and then, completely separately, creating properties of the same name on the `person` object.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to convert a string to title casing:

```
function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt){return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();});
}
```

See example usage:

```
var nameMixedCaseing = ["alan bong" , "JusTin weasel", "Tom curry"]

for (i = 0; i < nameMixedCaseing.length; i++)
    console.log(toTitleCase(nameMixedCaseing[i]));
```

Result is:

```
Alan Bong
Justin Weasel
Tom Curry
```

So in your code you can call this function before saving the person object

```
person.firstName = toTitleCase(person.firstName);
person.lastName = toTitleCase(person.lastName);
contacts.push(person);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of functions, one to capitalize, one to sort each time a new contact is pushed into the array:

```js
var contacts = [
    { 
        fname: 'andrew',
        lname: 'mCGonahan'
    },
    { 
        fname: 'paUla',
        lname: 'Ptrokva'
    },
    { 
        fname: 'kevin',
        lname: 'harGRove'
    },
    { 
        fname: 'CAmille',
        lname: 'dUpoIs'
    },
    { 
        fname: 'AlbERt',
        lname: 'sWanson'
    }
];

function capitalize(arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var first = arr[i].fname;
        var last = arr[i].lname;
        arr[i].fname = first.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() + first.slice(1).toLowerCase();
        arr[i].lname = last.slice(0,1).toUpperCase() +last.slice(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return arr;
}

function sortByLast(arr) { 
    return arr.sort(function(a, b) { 
        if (a.lname > b.lname) return 1;
        if (b.lname > a.lname) return -1;
        return 0;
    });
}

//you can call the following after you have pushed the newest contact into the array
// or you could capitalize the inputs as they are entered, then run the sort function on the contacts array
contacts = sortByLast(capitalize(contacts));


document.getElementById('sortedContacts').innerHTML  = JSON.stringify(contacts);
```

```html
<div id="sortedContacts"><h3></h3></div>
```